# Add-Content not appending to last output

Tags: powershell

I want to append an output to the last console output.

```
  $r = write-output "$server - $db"
  $r
  Add-Content $r -Value " : Success!"
```

essentially im trying to get this output:

> server - db : Success!

on MS docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-6

the examples assume a file is being used. isnt there a way to append to console output?

if i use -PassThru it outputs on next line, which i dont want

> server - db
>
> : Success!

Comment: `Add-Content` writes data to files. Are you just trying to concatenate strings? You have a dirty file in your working directory called `server - db` i imagine now

Comment: @Matt yes i want to add a status after an if statement later in my code to the last console output, so i thought Add-Content is for both uses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Add-Content` is specifically for adding content to an external resource such as a file. If you just want to append to a string you can just do this:

```
$r = "$Server - $DB"
$r
$r = $r + " : Success"
$r
```

Or you could use string interpolation like this:

```
$r = "$r : Success"
```

And anything you do that isn't sent somewhere else is going to print to the console by default, so you don't need to use `Write-Output` or even update the variable if your only goal is to get it on the screen, you can just put this on a line on its own:

```
"$r : Success"
```

If your goal is to write some text to the console and then later append some text to the same line, you can do that with `Write-Host`:

```
$r = "$Server - $DB"
Write-Host $r -NoNewLine
Write-Host " : Success"
```

Comment: i want r to print first and then append the success message later in the code.

Comment: Updated my answer to do that.

Comment: Oh if you want to append some text to the same line in the console then you need to use `Write-Host -nonewline` for the first part. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: this one prints: server - db, and then another line it prints server-db-success. i dont want r to be repeated twice.

Comment: perfect! now just to note: i have this in a forloop. does -nonewline switch affect this loop output? in other words, will every iteration append to the same line, or the nonewline is ignored from previous output?

Comment: the second use of `write-host` is not using `-nonewline` so it prints a newline character.

Comment: wait so what does this mean in terms of my for loop comment?

Comment: It means it should behave as you are intending, as far as I understand it.

Comment: great, so in iteration 2, the following would be printed: server - db - success! then in iteration3, another line: server - db - success! etc... right? with writehost -nonewline that is

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is concatenate the string.

The following example should give you the output desired:

```
$r = write-output "$server - $db"
$r += " : Success!"
$r
```

Comment: i want r to print first and then add the success message to it later. this one prints r after everything,...